# listView is not updated immediately

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have an Activity, which contains 2 dynamic Fragments (Exactly one of them is displayed at a time).
one of the Fragments (HasExploitsFragment) contains a listView.

When the activity resumes (the resume function has been called), (after an object added to the list)
the list (at the HasExploitsFragment fragment) is not updated..

The resume function is:

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (exploitTitleAndDescription.get(HasGroupsFragment.groupChosen)
                .size() == 0) {
            // Hide the fragment
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            fm.beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in,
                            android.R.animator.fade_out)
                    .hide(hasExploitsFragment).commit();
            addDynamicNoExploitsFragment();
        } else {
            //We enter this section, but despite that, the update is not shown immediately :(
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            fm.beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in,
                            android.R.animator.fade_out)
                    .hide(noExploitsFragment).commit();
            addDynamicHasExploitsFragment();    
        }
    }
```

and the addDynamicHasExploitsFragment() is the following:

```
private void addDynamicHasExploitsFragment() {
        hasExploitsFragment = new HasExploitsFragment();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.exploits_main_menu, hasExploitsFragment).commit();
    }
```

When I exit the Activity and enters again, the list is updated.
How can I perform the update immediately (At the resume function details above)?

Comment: did you call notifydatasetchanged() after adding?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer!
I didn't call it, because I'm creating a new Fragment
(See line: hasExploitsFragment = new HasExploitsFragment();) when the resume is called.
but apparently the creation is not done right... cause the new data is not shown up..

Comment: ok, it works... THANK YOU!!
post it as a comment and I'll upvote you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to update listview.